Electric Double Oven 10AWG on 40A breaker?
I've upgraded to a larger breaker panel and am reviewing wire sizes and breakers from prior installs before we purchased the home.  The home is located near Chicago and must follow Chicago electric code.
A kitchen double wall oven wiring is ran in 3/4" Emt and is 10AWG, 240V with Neutral. The nameplate power is 8.4kW with a 40A breaker originally installed. They ran 10AWG THHN wire with no other circuits in the conduit.
From the CEC/NEC tables I see 10AWG can take 40A,however a note (240.4) suggests the breaker should not exceed 30A.
I'm also trying to understand if table 220.55 derating applies here since the manufacturer stated to use a 40A breaker (no wire size was stated in the manual).  If I use the derating factor of 80%, 80% of 8.4kW = 6.72kW -> 6720W/240V = 28A.
So... Does derating apply in this condition or does this need to be changed to an 8AWG run?

TL;DR You need 8 AWG
We've got two different issues here:
Required Circuit Size
Manufacturer says 40A, that is what you use. Period. Which means:

Circuit Breaker = 40A
Wire Size = Any size that can handle at least 40A based on all other installation parameters
Actual usage is worked out in the design. The end-user doesn't need to worry about how much current can be carried on the wires, e.g., the 80% derate for continuous usage. That's up the manufacturer and UL or ETL or similar organizations to work out. They came up with 40A, that is the end.

As it turns out, 8,400W / 240V = 35A, which is less than 40A but more than the usual continuous derate of 30A. But you can't use a 35A breaker - doesn't matter if they exist or not, the manufacturer said 40A. I suspect that the oven uses up to 8,400W at times but less than 30A (7,200W) continuously. But again, not your concern.
As I understand it, the 220.55 calculations are for determining the overall Load of cooking equipment for a panel or service Load Calculation. And those calculations can indeed result in a single appliance getting a Load value that is less than the manufacturer's rating of the appliance! That has to do with the way appliances are used - even if you sometimes run the self-cleaning or preheat bake/broil + burners at the same time, most of the time you aren't doing that, even on Thanksgiving. So the circuit has to be sized based on the actual power needs at any given instant but the Load is more like a "best guess average when everything is used in a typical way".
Compatible Wire Types
The manufacturer didn't specify because it varies. Typical options include:

8 AWG copper cables (including NM-B, a.k.a. Romex) - up to 40A
8 AWG copper wires in conduit - up to 50A
8 AWG aluminum wires in conduit or cables (SE, USE) - up to 40A.

Note that I did NOT include 10 AWG copper wires. Why? Because 10 AWG copper wires are only allowed 40A with the 90 C rating. At the standard 75 C rating the maximum is 35A. And you can't use 35A wire on a 40A circuit. You can only use 90 C wire at a power level beyond the 75 C rating if everything in use - e.g., circuit breaker, connection to oven, etc. is also rated 90 C, and the assumption is most residential installations is that everything is rated for 75 C.
Thanks to nobody for a reference to NEC 240.4(D) which prohibits any ordinary circuits from using 10 AWG for anything larger than 30A. So even the 35A that I mentioned above (nominal 75 C copper rating) doesn't apply. It does matter for other things - e.g., derates for multiple circuits in one conduit - but when it comes to an ordinary circuit, 10 AWG copper maxes out at 30A.
3/4" EMT can handle 3 x 8 AWG without a problem.

Thanks for the quick response back. There is a junction box in the middle of the circuit I can easily get to. If the wire from the breaker to this is 8AWG, I use terminals (wagos or nuts) rated to higher than 90c, and leave the 10AWG to the oven from this box, would this comply? The oven is hard wired and installed with wire nuts.

That works (I think) but only if the oven connection is considered rated for 90 C, and I doubt that's the case. Unless I am missing something (which is possible) all the wire and components in a typical residential circuit are going to be 75 C rated (some parts may be 90 C rated, such as THHW and similar wire) and most cables only 60 C rated. But 90 C is rare to have for all parts of a circuit.

Thanks again.  I'll check with the manufacturer- but in the manual they do give a hint: "The 3 power leads supplied with this appliance are suitable for connection to heavier gauge household wiring. The insulation of these 3 leads is rated for temperatures much higher than the temperature rating of the household wiring."

That statement makes total sense. Here is the deal: Manufacturers can (with UL/ETL/etc. approval) use thinner wires inside the appliance than you can use outside the appliance. The catch is that, particularly for appliances that generate heat, they have to have appropriate insulation. But they don't want you to think that (a) if they use 8 AWG that you can't use larger than 8 AWG (you can, but don't need to) or that (b) if they use 10 AWG that you can use smaller than 8 AWG (you can't, most likely) because they play by different rules.

10AWG wire cannot be on a 40A circuit, period. The NEC restricts 10AWG to 30A maximum regardless of termination ratings in 240.4(D). https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/139470/how-do-i-derate-for-2-dryer-circuits-in-one-conduit
